# S3 Delete Object 400 Bad Request

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi, bucket, bad-request, 400-bad-request

I have a S3 bucket, which was under some testing to have some random folder and files.
I need to clear this bucket by deleting all its data objects.
But could not delete it from UI/Cyberduck app, by selecting delete or rename it just refreshes but nothing happens.
Bucket looks like:

```
-bucket_test_n1
 -Test-project
  -1.0.0
   -98dff-dr5-ft6
  -2.0.0
  -2.0.2
   -asdd89-jfjksjf67-ll
    -win.ini testfile-api.txt
```

I tried deleting files using NiFi processors also.

ListS3->DeleteS3Object

DeleteS3Object was able to delete most of the files, but could not delete few and sending them to failure queue.

I am trying to delete `bucket_test_n1/Test-project/1.0.0/98dff-dr5-ft6` folder using deletes3object processor in NiFi, but getting:

> failed to delete s3 object for flowfile[filename=`bucket_test_n1/Test-project/1.0.0/98dff-dr5-ft6/..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\windows\win.initestfile-api.txt`] routing to failure:com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service:Amazon S3;Status Code:400;Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID:null; S3 Extended Request ID:null;Proxy:null), S3 Extended Request ID:null

Please suggest how can this be deleted.

Comment: S3 error codes explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html). Unclear how you come to have so many `..\` segments in your object key but you really don't want those at all so you might want to take a look at how that happened in the first place.